# Perron's formula application - zeros of $L(s,\chi )$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration, dirichlet-series, mobius-function

After applying Perron's formula I have a complex integral involving something like
\[ \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\mu (n)}{n^s}e\left (\frac {an}{q}\right ).\]
As usual ("usual" meaning e.g. proof of the PNT or the explicit formula) I want to move the integral to the left and therefore have to consider the poles of the above function.  By splitting the $n$ according to the residue modulo $q$ I have to consider the poles of something like
\[ \sum _{\chi (q)}\chi (r)L^{-1}(s,\chi ).\]
(Let's also suppose I did everything above involving the logarithmic derivative, so that all poles are simple).

What can I say about these poles?  Now, I really want to move the integral to the left, so I get an expression like that in the explicit formula.  However, I will ultimately sum over $a=1,...,q$ (as well as the $\chi $ coming from my $n$ split, which I don't know if it was a good or bad move).  Is it hopeless to hope to be able to say anything about the $a$ or $\chi $ dependence?

I should maybe also say: I'm happy with the size of real parts of the zeros (I don't want to use any RH assumptions or anything - I think the sizes are ok.  What I want is to be able to use $a$ or $\chi $ cancellation.  I actually have the modulus squared of all the above and then I sum over $a$.).

Comment: There are versions of explicit formulas that only contain truncated sum over nontrivial zeros. Have a look at Davenport's GTM74.

Comment: what reference is that sorry, not following?  oh, i get that it's truncated, should have written that, but do these versions have anything explicit about the character itself?  (does that question even make sense? i'm not sure what i expect - i just know i want to be able to sum over the characters)

Comment: The book is named _Multiplicative Number Theory_ by Harold Davenport, and I believe its chapter 19 and 20 are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: oh no i know that reference.  i mean in the explicit formula all we know is that rho is a zero of L(s,chi) right, and nothing more.  there's no way to sum the explicit formula over chi non-trivially?  if that makes any sense

Comment: I think bounding sum over nonprincipal characters is sufficient to obtain satisfactory O term for your problem, as this is the case in Siegel-Walfisz and Bombieri-Vinogradov theorems.

Comment: ye but obviously i have a different problem - it's a fact that i need to find cancellation in $a$ or i guess $chi $.  dunno.